# How to avoid duplicate database connection in java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have 2 classes. C_DB and C_Test.

In C_DB, getConnection() method returns a connection. If I call getConnection() multiple times, it's gonna re-connect to the DB and return multiple connection.

Is there a way I can avoid this? I want to check if a connection does exist, then just return that connection instead of create a new one. So there will be only 1 connection to db.

**C_DB**

```
public class C_DB {
    Connection con;

    public C_DB() {
        String dbLink = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbLink, dbUser, dbPass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("DB Errors: ", e);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }
}
```

**C_Test**

```
public class C_Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection con1 = new C_DB().getConnection(); // new connection
        Connection con2 = new C_DB().getConnection(); // new duplicate connection
        Connection con3 = new C_DB().getConnection(); // new duplicate connection
    }

}
```

Comment: I suppose you just check whether the connection is not null.

Comment: Use a [**Connection Pool**](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

Comment: I suppose @Ravi approach would be best.. here is a example .http://codethataint.com/blog/using-singleton-class-for-db-connection-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Connection Pool and set it max pool size to 1 as @Elliott pointed out in the comment or you can implement something like this.

```
public class C_DB {

    private static C_DB instance;

    private Connection con;

    private C_DB() {
        String dbLink = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "";
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbLink, dbUser, dbPass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("DB Errors: ", e);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        if(instance == null){
           instance = new C_DB();
        }
        return instance.con;
    }

}
```

Comment: The above is extremely prone to bugs in multi-threaded programs. Don't do this, use a connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`Singleton`** design pattern to avoid multiple instances.

something like this :

```
public class C_DB {

    private static final Connection con;
    private static final C_DB singleInstance;

    private C_DB() {
        String dbLink = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbLink, dbUser, dbPass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("DB Errors: ", e);
        }
    }

    public static C_DB getInstance() {
        if (singleInstance == null) {
            synchronized (C_DB.class) {
                if (singleInstance == null) {
                    singleInstance = new C_DB();
                }
            }
        }

        return singleInstance;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }
}
```

And get the connection as :

```
Connection con = C_DB.getInstance().getConnection();
```